# jena.query.ResultSet and jena.query.QuerySolution: empty iterator after SPARQL request

Tags: sparql, jena

A have a problem with receiving SPARQL response. A problem is method 
`((ResultSet) response).hasNext()` returns `false` despite response shouldn't be empty.

Request is:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> 
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX ontology: <http://www.semanticweb.org/kseniia/ontologies/2013/1/untitled-ontology-12#> SELECT ?x 
WHERE {?x rdfs:subClassOf ontology:Visual}
```

This works correctly in Protege and returns 3 objects:

```
Location
Relation
Descriptive
```

Query was executed in jena such way:

```
Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
Object response = qexec.execSelect();
qexec.close();
for ( ; ((ResultSet) response).hasNext(); ) {   // always false
   QuerySolution soln = ((ResultSet) response).nextSolution();
   // etc
}
```

Maybe I missed something?

Answer (score 3):

You are closing the execution with `qexec.close`, then iterating over the results.  Except the results are closed by the `qexec.close` and no longer available.

Move the `qexec.close` to after the loop.

Improvement:

`Object response`
==>
`ResultSet response`