# Getting Jena Resultset after closing query - for modularity

Tags: java, database, resultset, jena

I have the following situation:

- `Class B` has a method that receives a String with a query, executes it
  and return the `Resultset`.
- `Class A` creates a SPARQL query and calls the method in `Class B`.

The problem is, when `Class A` gets the `Resultset` object back, it is empty! Of course because the Query is closed in `Class B` (see [jena.query.ResultSet and jena.query.QuerySolution: empty iterator after SPARQL request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698578/jena-query-resultset-and-jena-query-querysolution-empty-iterator-after-sparql-r)).

My question is, how can this be made modular at all? I want to have a `Class B` that only executes SPARQL queries, without having to know about the result structure or anything. And I want `Class B` to deal with the query creation and the query closing, because it makes no sense that `Class A` does it.

```
Class B:

 try {
            Query query = QueryFactory.create(myQuery);
            qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, ontology);
            ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();
            return results;
        } catch (...){
            ...
        } finally {
            ...
                qe.close();
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `ResultSet` is almost always streaming by default so you are quite right in saying that closing the `QueryExecution` will cause the `ResultSet` to act as if it is empty

You can take a reusable in-memory copy of a `ResultSet` using the [ResultSetFactory.copyResults()](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/com/hp/hpl/jena/query/ResultSetFactory.html#copyResults%28com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet%29) method and pass that back instead e.g.

```
ResultSet results = ResultSetFactory.copyResults(qe.execSelect());
```

This allows class B to safely close the `QueryExecution` and provides a non-empty `ResultSet` to the calling code assuming of course that the query produces any answers in the first place!